# Swift variable not holding value or resetting itself somehow

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to keep score in a game which has different point values associated with different things. The user has to touch things in the game to get the points. However the score is not being calculated accurately.

I have determined that the score associated which each element in the game is being stored properly in a variable called `ballValue`. The variable `currentScore` is used to hold the score and then I'm using a `SKLabelNode` to display the value of `currentScore`.

`currentScore` is initialized with a value of 0 and is updated with its current value plus `ballValue` when a user touches a ball.

**Update to show code and context**

```
class ChallengeScene: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Ball Data
    var randomBallType : Int = 0
    var ballValue : Int = 0

    // MARK: HUD
    var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Impact")
    var timeLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Impact")

    var currentScore : Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.scoreLabel.text = "\(self.currentScore)"
            GameHandler.sharedInstance.score = currentScore
        }
    }

    // MARK: Initial Setup
    func createHUD() {
    ... UNRELATED HUD STUFF...
        currentScore = 0
    }

    // MARK: Gameplay Setup
    func createBall(forTrack track: Int) {
        setupTracks()

        randomBallType = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 9)

        switch randomBallType {
        case 0:
            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blueOne")
            ballSpeed = 0.008
            ballValue = 1
        case 1:
            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "minusThree")
            ballSpeed = 0.008
            ballValue = -3
        case 2:
            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "minusFive")
            ballSpeed = 0.008
            ballValue = -5
        case 3:
            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "purpleThree")
            ballSpeed = 0.008
            ballValue = 3
        case 4:
            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenFive")
            ballSpeed = 0.008
            ballValue = 5
        case 5:
            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blackTen")
            ballSpeed = 0.008
            ballValue = 10
        default:
            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blueOne")
            ballSpeed = 0.008
            ballValue = 1
        }

        player?.name = "BALL"
        player?.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        player?.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

        ...UNRELATED BALL STUFF...

        self.addChild(player!)
    }

    // MARK: Overrides
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        createHUD()
        launchGameTimer()

        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run {
            self.createBall(forTrack: self.track)
            }, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)])))

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let node = self.nodes(at: location).first

            if node?.name == "BALL" {
                currentScore = currentScore + ballValue
                node?.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        // GAME TIMER RELATED STUFF

    }
}
```

I think I know where the problem happens (in the touches override), I just don't understand why it is happening. If you could help in anyway that would be awesome

Comment: The logic doesn't seem right.. Every time you instantiate a `Ball`, the `ballValue` changes.. In other words, this looks like a global property instead of a class level property (each ball should have a ball value) instead of a single instance shared among all balls.. Therefore, when you do `currentScore = currentScore + ballValue`, it actually does `currentScore` + the last ball's value that was instantiated.. At least this is the conclusion with the amount of code you've shared..

Comment: @Brandon If it's not a global property how would I be able to add `ballValue` to `currentScore` upon each touch? I had `var ballValue : Int = 0` inside `class ChallengeScene: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {` if that what you mean

Comment: @Brandon I updated the post to show more context

Comment: "However the score is not being calculated accurately." What does that mean? What score do you get, and what score do you expect and why? "I think I know where the problem happens" Yes, but you still haven't even told _us_ what the problem _is_. Have you tried putting a breakpoint and just walking thru `touchesBegan` to see exactly what's happening? You have a wonderful debugger; debug! (Also put a breakpoint on the `currentScore` getter so that you see exactly what's going on every time the score gets changes, and who is changing it.)

Comment: @matt That's sort of my point, I think I know where the issue is, I just don't understand why. And I'm expecting it to do math correctly - so when `currentScore` is 0 and I touch a ball with `ballValue` of 5 `currentScore` should be updated to 5 not 3 (for example). Sorry if I come off as unwilling to try solving it myself, I'm just starting out with iOS development and I've been trying to figure it out all day so I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: If you do what I suggested, you will know _instantly_ why `currentScore` is updated to 5 not 3. The breakpoint will stop the code and you will see the entire call chain at that moment along with the values of the variables at every level of the call chain. Just try it! Solve your own problem. Learn to fish, don't ask us to hand you a fish.

Comment: @matt Great suggestion thank you, I figured out that the issue is that every time a new ball is created the value of `ballValue` is reset to whatever that new ball sets it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single `ballValue` property. Every time you spawn a new ball, you set `ballValue` as appropriate for **that newly-created ball**. What about all the other existing balls? A touch on any of them will also be worth that same `ballValue`.

When a ball is touched, you need to know the proper value for **the touched ball**, which may be different than the value of the most-recently-created ball. What you probably want to do is create a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` that represents a ball, and holds its own value:

```
class BallNode: SKSpriteNode {
    let value: Int

    init(imageName: String, speed: CGFloat, value: Int) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)
        self.value = value
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .init(white: 1, alpha: 0), size: texture.size())
        self.speed = speed
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}
```

Create the balls like this:

```
func createBall(forTrack track: Int) {
```

//        setupTracks()

```
    randomBallType = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 9)

    let ball: BallNode
    switch randomBallType {
    case 0: ball = BallNode(imageNamed: "blueOne", speed: 0.008, value: 1)
    case 1: ball = BallNode(imageNamed: "minusThree", speed: 0.008, value: -3)
    case 2: ball = BallNode(imageNamed: "minusFive", speed: 0.008, value: -5)
    // etc.
    }

    ball.name = "BALL"
    ball.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

    // ...UNRELATED BALL STUFF...

    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

Then, to handle a touch, use the touched ball's value to update the score:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if let ball = self.nodes(at: location).flatMap({ $0 as? BallNode }).first {
            currentScore += ball.value
            ball.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another (not necessarily better) option would be to use the `userData` property to associate data with a SKNode.

Comment: I've been banging my head against a wall all day with this issue. Thank you.